# Set the value of a resource's String (example String1)

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net i found the way to read the value of String1.
But is there a way to set it and then save for future use?

To read i used this:

```
 My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("String1")
```

It works. But if i want to set a new value to String1, how i do it?
I searched on google but i only found how to write in txt files inside resources, and not simple strings always set in the project property resources.

Also, to save the new string, if it can be done, I should use

```
My.Settings.Save
```

?

Comment: See this question: [reading-string-from-resource-file-and-editing-it-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772976/reading-string-from-resource-file-and-editing-it-programmatically).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a resource value at runtime. Period.

If you don't want to use the registry or a configuration file, then you need to look into the use of [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx).