# How to loop through all resource files of a solution looking for a key?

Tags: c#, resx

I have a resx file with a huge number of keys and their values in L1 (Language 1) which I got from a translator. The problem is that this resx file has a lot of keys which are present in the solution in different resx files for both L1 and L2.

What I need to do is read each key from my master L1 resx file, search through all resx files in the solution ( I'll enter the base path ) and when the key is found in L2.resx, update its value in corresponding L1.resx. If key isn't found in L2, insert it along with its value in L1.resx.

Any help on this regard would be great!

Comment: Could you please post some code that you have already tried?

Comment: Resx files are basically xml files, so you can create a small script that does this for you, in any language of your choice (not necessarily C#).

Comment: as @AdrianFaciu said, you cannot do this. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772976/reading-string-from-resource-file-and-editing-it-programmatically for a possible alternative